# Custom form set custom template

Tags: 8, forms

I have created a custom module for **custom form**, form is created successfully. But when I open this form then it's open under **MYTHEME/template/layout/page.html.twig** I just need to open this form in other template.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your form would be in `core/modules/system/templates/form.html.twig`:
if you want to override it to twig in  your module try the following :

1. Implement [hook_theme_suggestions_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.2.x)

```
    function YourModuleName_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook)
    {
        if (isset($variables['element']) && isset($variables['element']['#type']) && $variables['element']['#type'] == 'form') {
            $original_theme_hook = $variables['theme_hook_original'];
            array_unshift($suggestions, $original_theme_hook . '__' . str_replace('-', '_', $variables['element']['#id']));
        }
    }
```

2. Implement [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.2.x)

```
function YpurModuleName_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return [
       'form__YouFormId_form' => [
            'base hook' => 'form',
        ],
    ];
}
```

3. Create a folder Called `templates`.
4. Copy and past `core/modules/system/templates/form.html.twig` to your `templates` folder.
5. Rename `form.html.twig` to `form--YourFormId-form.html.twig` .
6. Rebuild Cache.

Comment: Thanks berramou, for quick reply.
When I created a custom theme, then I was get all folder under /templates/ like admin, block, content, form, layout etc from dummy theme. theme was configure properly.

Comment: Thanks berramou, for quick reply. When I created a custom theme, then I was get all folder under /templates/ like admin, block, content, form, layout etc from dummy theme. theme was configure properly. Then I was created a new module for custom form, form is working fine. 

All working fine. 

The problem is when I open this form form it's open in page.html.twig in default template.

I want to open this form in other .html.twig template. 

Also I was follow your procedure but it's not working.

Comment: You are welcome, if you want to override page.html.twig you can copy and paste it to your templates folder in your dummy theme. but  this page will override all page not only your form page. Good luck

Comment: resume is my module name, I have created resume.module file, and added your suggested code,

Comment: `function resume_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook)
    {
        if (isset($variables['element']) && isset($variables['element']['#type']) && $variables['element']['#type'] == 'form') {
            $original_theme_hook = $variables['theme_hook_original'];
            array_unshift($suggestions, $original_theme_hook . '__' . str_replace('-', '_', $variables['element']['#id']));
        }
    }`

Comment: `function resume_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return [
       'form__resume_form_form' => [
            'base hook' => 'form',
        ],
    ];
}`

Comment: also created a new template named form--resume-form-form.html and listed under  **\themes\THEMENAME\templates\form**

Comment: But still form displaying under **themes\THEMENAME\templates\layout\page.html**

Comment: Your form template  should be `form--FormId-form-form.html.twig`.  FormId is your form id if you created your form programmatically Form Id is your `getFormId` function.  Can you give your Form ID i will refactor the code fro you .